Conditions on the Endowment to make the core a singleton set
I have been asked to state and prove the conditions on endowments to ensure core to be a singleton set.
I claim that if the endowment itself is Pareto Optimal then the core would be a singleton set consisting of the endowment itself, however I am having a hard time proving my claim.(This idea might be completely wrong but this is what I've got so far)
$
\text{Claim: if the endowment } \textit{e} \text{ is PO then } \mathbb{C} = \{e\}\\
\text{Proof:} \\ \text{Let the endowment point $e \in \mathbb{C} \Rightarrow e$ is Pareto Optimal and} \color{red}{ \text{ e is Pareto Superior to itself. }} \\
\text{Let $x$ be an allocation such that $x \neq e$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}$}\\
\text{$\Rightarrow x$ is Pareto Optimal and $x$ is Pareto Superior to the endowment $e$}\\
\text{But since $e$ is assumed to be Pareto Optimal there cant exist any Allocation that is Pareto Superior to e.}\\
\text{And hence we arrive at a Contradiction}
$
My proof doesn't work because how can $e$ be Pareto Superior to itself.
Moreover my proof starts from the fact that $e$ is in the Core, but I need to show that if $e$ is PO then $e$ will be in the core.
How do I proceed further?
Thank you.

Why do you need $e$ to be Pareto Superior to itself?

According to what I have studied, an allocation belongs to the core if two conditions hold, first the allocation needs to be Pareto Optimum and Second it needs to be pareto superior to the endowment. Now if i claim that e belongs to the core shouldn't I require that it must be Pareto Sup to itself? I might be wrong here, thank you for your help anyway.

@YashBurman Are you assuming its a two consumer pure exchange economy?

@YashBurman I don’t think this is how you define Core. Given the way you have defined Core in the comments - that it consists of Pareto optimal allocations that are Pareto Superior to the endowment allocation, the core will be empty if endowment allocation is Pareto efficient.

Consider the following example of a two-consumer, two-goods pure exchange economy:

Utility functions: $u_1(x_1,y_1)=x_1+y_1$, $u_2(x_2,y_2)=x_2+y_2$
Endowments: $\omega_1=(2,0)$, $\omega_2=(0,2)$

Set of feasible allocations is
$\mathcal{F}=\{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))\in\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+|x_1+x_2=2 \ \wedge \ y_1+y_2=2\}$
Observe that the set of Pareto efficient allocations equals the set of feasible allocations:
$\mathcal{PE}=\mathcal{F}$
So, endowment is Pareto efficient. But core consists of all allocations on the diagonal of the Edgeworth box that satisfy $x_1+y_1=2$. So, Core equals
$\mathcal{C}=\{((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))\in\mathcal{F}|x_1+y_1=2\}$
and it is not singleton.
So, you cannot prove that if the endowment is Pareto optimal then the core is singleton.
I suggest that you try to prove the following proposition:
In a 2 consumer pure exchange economy, if the endowment allocation is Pareto optimal and all utility functions are strictly quasi-concave (or preferences are strictly convex) then the core is singleton and consists of the endowment allocation

Claim: If the endowment is Pareto optimal, then the core is a singleton set.

Notations:

$\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2\}$ denotes the set of all individuals.
$\mathbb{M} = \{1, 2\}$ denotes the set of all goods.
$\mathbb{C}$ denotes the set of all allocations that satisfy the core property.
$u^i(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$, is the utility function of the $i^{\text{th}}$ agent.

The utility function of every agent is assumed to be strictly quasi-concave (implying strictly convex indifference curves), continuous, and strongly increasing.


$\mathbf{e} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}_{+}$ is the endowment vector, where $\mathbf{e}^i_j \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $\mathbf{e}^i \in \mathbb{R}^2_{+}$ denote the endowment of the $j^{\text{th}}$ good available to the $i^{\text{th}}$ agent and the endowment vector of the $i^{\text{th}}$ agent, respectively.


Proof:
The endowment $\mathbf{e}$ is Pareto optimal. Since $\mathbf{e}$ is at least as good as itself and feasible, it satisfies the core property. Hence, $\mathbf{e} \in \mathbb{C}$.
Now, let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}_{+}$ be another feasible allocation such that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{e}$.
Then $\mathbf{x}$ must also be Pareto optimal and at least as good as the endowment. That is, the following must hold:
1.
$$
   \neg \left(\exists \; \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}_{+} \right) \left[ (\forall i \in \mathbb{N}) \big(u(\mathbf{y}^i) \geq u(\mathbf{x}^i) \land (\exists j \in \mathbb{N}) (u(\mathbf{y}^j) > u(\mathbf{x}^j))\big) \right]
   $$
2.
$$u(\mathbf{x}^i) \geq u(\mathbf{e}^i) \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$$
From (2), consider the following cases:

Case 1:
$\exists \; k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $u(\mathbf{x}^k) > u(\mathbf{e}^k)$.
This implies:
$\mathbf{x}$ is Pareto superior to $\mathbf{e} \implies \mathbf{e}$ is not Pareto optimal.
This is a contradiction.

Case 2:
$u(\mathbf{x}^i) = u(\mathbf{e}^i) \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.
This implies:
$u(\mathbf{x})$ and $u(\mathbf{e})$ lie on the same indifference curve.
Moreover, since both $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are Pareto optimal:
The indifference curves of all individuals are tangent at both $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{e}$.
However, since indifference curves are strictly convex:
This implies either $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{e}$, or there are multiple points of tangency.
The latter cannot occur because of strict convexity, and the former contradicts the assumption that $\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{e}$.
In either case, we arrive at a contradiction.

Therefore, the core consists of a single allocation, which is the endowment itself.
As a corollary, we conclude that if the endowment satisfies the core property, the Walrasian equilibrium is the endowment.
